# Kotlin does not check for return statement in function with some return type in function signature

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class TestReturnFunction{
fun convertIntToString(intVal:Int?):String{
    intVal?.let {
        return it.toString()
    }
}
}
```

In the above TestReturnFunction, there is a naive function which converts int to String . Inside the function we use let keyword , which will run a code block only when the argument to let is non null . So, the return statement inside the let will only run when the argument is non null.

The problem with above is that there is no return statement for the case when intVal is null and the Android studio does not give any error .

If we check the documentation for let keyword in kotlin, it says:

> Calls the specified function [block] with `this` value as its argument and returns its result.

Further, the issue is that if we look into the java bytecode for above kotlin code , it looks like below

```
public final class TestReturnFunction {
@NotNull
public final String convertIntToString(@Nullable Integer intVal) {
  if (intVal != null) {
     int it = ((Number)intVal).intValue();
     return String.valueOf(it);
  } else {
     return null;
  }
 }
}
```

Now , the problem with this code is that the function returns null in the case intVal is null but the function return type is of non nullable type . 
Is this the bug or feature? anyone faced this issue before ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug which was present in Kotlin version 1.3.0.

see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28061

If possible upgrade to a Kotlin version >= 1.3.20